# how to search contacts using phone number, name and email

Tags: android

I have created a contact manager app, in this I want to search the contacts using name, phone number or email. If I type phone number, contacts having typed number should be displayed and in case of name and email.

I have tried but search using email is not working. Searching using name and phone is just worked fine.

My code is,

```
search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String newText = search.getText().toString();
            String regexStr = "^[0-9]*$";

            if(newText.trim().matches(regexStr))
                adapter.filterUsingNumber(newText);
            else {
                if(isEmailValid(newText))
                    adapter.filterUsingEmail(newText);
                else
                    adapter.filter(newText);
            }
        }
    });
}

public static boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
    String expression = "^(([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\\w-]{2,}))@"
            + "((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
            + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\."
            + "([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
            + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
            + "([a-zA-Z]+[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$";

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(email);
    return matcher.matches();
}
```

Error is,

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at contacts.com.contactsmanager.SelectUserAdapter.filterUsingEmail(SelectUserAdapter.java:160)
        at contacts.com.contactsmanager.MainActivity$1.afterTextChanged(MainActivity.java:97)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7334)
        at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:9087)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:970)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:497)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:435)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
        at android.text.method.QwertyKeyListener.onKeyDown(QwertyKeyListener.java:223)
        at android.text.method.TextKeyListener.onKeyDown(TextKeyListener.java:136)
        at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:5464)
        at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:5283)
        at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2623)
        at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:7343)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1393)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1393)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1393)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1393)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1393)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1393)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1933)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1408)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2384)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:49)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:265)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1860)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3791)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3774)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3483)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3540)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3516)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3666)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:1982)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1698)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1689)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:1959)
        at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:132)
```

My adapter code is,

```
public class SelectUserAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
public List<SelectUser> _data;
private ArrayList<SelectUser> arraylist;
Context _c;
ViewHolder v;
RoundImage roundedImage;

public SelectUserAdapter(List<SelectUser> selectUsers, Context context) {
    _data = selectUsers;
    _c = context;
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<SelectUser>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(_data);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return _data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return _data.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) _c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = li.inflate(R.layout.contacts_list, null);
        Log.e("Inside", "here--------------------------- In view1");
    } else {
        view = convertView;
        Log.e("Inside", "here--------------------------- In view2");
    }

    v = new ViewHolder();

    v.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    //v.check = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
    //v.phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.no);
    v.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);

    final SelectUser data = (SelectUser) _data.get(i);
    v.title.setText(data.getName());
    //v.check.setChecked(data.getCheckedBox());
    //v.phone.setText(data.getPhone());

    // Set image if exists
    try {

        if (data.getThumb() != null) {
            v.imageView.setImageBitmap(data.getThumb());
            Bitmap bm = data.getThumb();
            roundedImage = new RoundImage(bm);
            v.imageView.setImageDrawable(roundedImage);
        } else {
            v.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.noimage);
        }
        // Seting round image
        //Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(view.getResources(), R.drawable.noimage); // Load default image
        //roundedImage = new RoundImage(bm);
        //v.imageView.setImageDrawable(roundedImage);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        // Add default picture
        v.imageView.setImageDrawable(this._c.getDrawable(R.drawable.noimage));
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.e("Image Thumb", "--------------" + data.getThumb());

    /*// Set check box listener android
    v.check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view;
            if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                data.setCheckedBox(true);
              } else {
                data.setCheckedBox(false);
            }
        }
    });*/

    view.setTag(data);
    return view;
}

// Filter Class Using Name
public void filter(String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    _data.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        _data.addAll(arraylist);
    } else {
        for (SelectUser wp : arraylist) {
            if (wp.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                    .contains(charText)) {
                _data.add(wp);
            }
            else {
                filterUsingEmail(charText);
                Toast.makeText(_c, "adasd", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

// Filter Class Using Name
public void filterUsingNumber(String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    _data.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        _data.addAll(arraylist);
    } else {
        for (SelectUser wp : arraylist) {
            if (wp.getPhone().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                    .contains(charText)) {
                _data.add(wp);
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

// Filter Class Using Email
public void filterUsingEmail(String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    _data.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        _data.addAll(arraylist);
    } else {
        for (SelectUser wp : arraylist) {
            if (wp.getEmail().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                    .contains(charText)) {
                _data.add(wp);
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView title, phone;
    CheckBox check;
}
}
```

Is there any way to search using these 3 items. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check what this function `wp.getEmail().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)` returns...

Comment: @Boss : this function returns contacts having searched email.

Comment: No that function returns either `true` or `false`. Please check that..

Comment: @Boss : it return `true` if email id is typed and `false` if not.

Comment: What? That function compares the data typed and the data in your `arraylist`, I am asking you to check what that function returns. May be its false, may be `_data` is empty.

Comment: post your isEmailValid()

Comment: @Boss : `java.lang.NullPointerException at contacts.com.contactsmanager.SelectUserAdapter.filterUsingEmail(SelectUserAdapter.java:160)`

Comment: Please append your complete logcat with your question. If its a `NullpointerException` check what is null

Comment: As Boss said, use the debugger and pinpoint where the program is saying the value is null, and if the value is ever not null before that point.

Comment: @JithinVarghese check all the SelectUsers email initialized.

Comment: post your full adapter code

Comment: @pskink : check the edited code.

Comment: and how do you create `SelectUserAdapter` ? how do you populate `selectUsers` list ?

Comment: never mind, this is a complete (but not customized code - you need to override Adapter's getView to make it look more natural): http://codeshare.io/Sh3h6

Comment: @pskink : thanks. I will try the given link.

Comment: as i said you have to make custom adapter (just override `getView`, nothing more) - now it showss everything in one `TextView`